# Display the metric number on home page, not "View Dashboard"

Tags: lightning

I've done this before but I'm hung up on this and can't get past it. I've added a dashboard (a single metric) to my home page and can't get the "big number" to display. It just shows as "View Dashboard". When I click on it, I see what I want, but that big number should be visible when I land on the home page.

This is what it looks like:
[image: Home Page]

I created the dashboard on just 2 tiles, as shown here:

[image: Dashboard on 2 tiles]

Thanks!